# mysql query to join

Tags: mysql

hey i have two tables i want to get the combined result out of two the structure is like this

tableA

```
id        user
1         2
2         2
3         3
4         2
5         2
6         3
```

tableB

```
id       credit
1        45
2        43
3        23
4        25
5        26
```

in both table id is autoincrement and tableA.user=tableB.id so i tried to execute this query but it returns empty result

```
sql_query("SELECT * from tableA join tableB  ON tableA.user=tableB.id " );
```

Comment: are the datatypes the same between the tableA.user column and the tableB.id column?

Comment: yes   see several places column user is coming in tableA. if you will count you will find that it is coming 4 places so i want to sum the views in tableA for user say 2 in this case . my query for that is SELECT sum(views) as num from tableA join tableB ON tableA.user=tableB.id where user='2'

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly against the db? If so, does it produce results there? btw SELECT * is not considered good practice these days. Specify the columns you want returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql_query("SELECT * from tableA inner join tableB  ON tableA.user=tableB.id where tableA.user=tableB.id" );
```

This will give u only those records which fulfilled your condition of joining.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *

```
SELECT *
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss * between SELECT and FROM

```
sql_query("SELECT * from tableA join tableB  ON tableA.user=tableB.id " );
```

Comment: see several places column user is coming in tableA. if you will count you will find that it is coming 4 places so i want to sum the views in tableA for user say 2 in this case . my query for that is  SELECT sum(views) as num from tableA join tableB  ON tableA.user=tableB.id where user='2'